# Aligning widget in RelativeLayout with a widget in nested LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

So I've been looking around for awhile now and can't seem to find an answer to my question

I have tried a few things, but nothing seems to work so I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Basically I have a RelativeLayout at the base of my XML Layout, and within that RelativeLayout I have some nested LinearLayouts, what I want to do is align a widget in the RelativeLayout to a TextView nested within a LinearLayout, so something like below (unnecessary XML markup has been removed so you can see what I'm trying to do easier)

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>        
        <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/TextView1"/>
        <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/TextView2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
       android:layout_alignLeft="@id/TextView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

At this point I've simply given up attempting to do this and removed the linear layouts from my XML and gone strictly with just the RelativeLayout.

However I'd just like to know if what I originally attempted is possible, and if I was just doing it wrong, or because of the way the widget is nested within another layout that it just doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is missing the point (lack of context, but that doesn't matter if I manage to help), but it sounds like you should be able to replace TextView2 with a horizontal LinearLayout containing both TextView2 and the external TextView. But, yes, sticking totally with a RelativeLayout will do a similar thing with more control (I just like nested LinearLayouts, and personally, I'd probably replace the entire RelativeLayout with them, depending on what it's for).

Comment: Thanks for that, I just gave this a try with some of my old code and it did exactly what I wanted it to do... wish I had found out about this earlier but oh well. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Elements in a RelativeLayout will only align with other elements in the same layout at the same level (siblings).

However, you may be able to achieve something like this with a little work.  You could put an ID on the LinearLayout.  You could then align the outer TextView with the LinearLayout and use padding and margin attributes (on both TextView2 and the outer TextView) to make it truly line up at display time.

Comment: I actually did try this, but I was worried that whilst they may align on the device I'm using to test, it may not align properly on another device. With what your suggesting, would this be the case?

Comment: If you stick with everything in dips (you should always anyway) then I would expect it to align anywhere.  There could be the possibility of rounding leading to 1 pixel misalignment but hopefully not.  The LinearLayout steps above will be sure on the alignment but depending on depth and reuse count the LinearLayout approach will be a fair bit heavier than a RelativeLayout.  See http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html for a discussion of that.

Comment: thanks for the link to the article, was rather insightful. However my layout is only two levels deep and is not being reused anywhere as my layout is purely static and not nested in a scrollable view. Thanks alot for your help :)